# reason of NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type

Tags: ios, swift2

i'm stuck here from past 2 hours still have no clue what the heck is wrong here :

in my backend i have values say  have tables named `Dogs` and `Cats`

my dogs table's one column is related to cats table (one to many relation)

now i'm trying to get the values of my dogs table but i'm keep getting thins error :

```
fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type
```

my Code:

```
//object classes 
class Dogs : NSObject {
    var id : String?
    var cats : [Cats]?
}

class Cats : NSObject {
    var rats : [Rats]?
    var name : String?
}
```

here i retrieved the Dogs Class from my Backend and after that

```
for dog in dogs  { // dogs is an array of Dogs Object
print(dog.id) // expected output 
print((dog.cats) // here i'm getting the error
```

In debugger the value of `dog.cats` is :

```
id  String? "dog1"
cats    [MyPackage.ViewController.Cats]?    Some
```

i also confirmed that cats have value in it  by printing `dog.cats.count` which is returning the total objects (Expected behaviour)

any one knows why is this happening ??

Comment: Have you accidentally declared your Cats class inside your view controller class?  It should be in its own Swift file.

Comment: yeah , is it the problem ?

Comment: Yes, since your array now contains `ViewController.Cats` not `Cats`

Comment: thanks a lot man , it took my so many hours still  you saved my next couple of hours :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared your `Cats` class inside the `ViewController` class, which means that you array contains `ViewComtroller.Cats` objects, not `Cats`.

Declare your `Cats` (and your `Dogs` class) in their own .swift files

Answer (score 1):

This is because the compiler will add @objc to NSObject subclasses. So you'll get an NSArray by default. So add @nonobjc to those property/function/class that you don't want to expose to Objective-C. And you'll get Swift Array.

```
class Dogs : NSObject {
    var id : String?
    @nonobjc var cats : [Cats]?
}
```

### Updated

It'll not add @objc by default in Swift 4.